# Is there any line continuation character (& _) available in PHP?

Tags: php, sql

I am dealing with long queries in PHP, so that I need to write it on multiple lines, but I don't know if their any line continuation character is available in PHP.

I used the same in **VB.NET** as furnished below:

```
sql = "SELECT stoks,srate,prate,taxp," & _
"iname,suplier,icod FROM stock where iname='" & item_name.Text & "'" & _
"and  suplier ='" & suplier.Text & " '"
```

Is there any similar operation available in PHP, for denoting **line continuation**?

Comment: PHP can handle that already as shown in the answers. But you can also try [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: Asked in 2014 (nearly 6 years after Stack Overflow launched) this must be a duplicate. But a search for "continuation character PHP" did not turn up anything on the first search page.

Comment: Where is ***the duplicate***? [Google-fu](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Google-fu) is sought for.

Answer (score 15):

In PHP, once you don't close the quotation, you can write your code on multiple lines. Example:

```
$sql = "select stoks,srate,prate,taxp,
        iname,suplier,icod from stock where iname='".$item_name."'
        AND  suplier ='".$suplier." '";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: *Please, please please*, stop promoting the use of the `mysql_*` library, even if it is only for illustrative purposes.  `mysql_` is so, so, so deprecated.

Comment: This gives you a lot of unneeded whitespace in the string right? Admittedly, not very important in the case of the above SQL.

Comment: I was looking for the exact opposite of this, because I need a solution that doesn't include the newlines and tabs as part of the quote.

Answer (score 5):

PHP is different from the various versions of VB in that it uses a line termination character.  (http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)  As such there is no line continuation character required.  Your long strings can just continue from line to line with no need to close the quotation.

```
$sql = "select stoks,srate,prate,taxp,
        iname,suplier,icod from stock where iname='".$item_name."'
        AND  suplier ='".$suplier." '";
```

Or you can close the quotation block and connect it to another one using the period concatenation operator "."

```
$sql = "select stoks,srate,prate,taxp," .
       "iname,suplier,icod from stock where iname='" . $item_name . "'" .
       " AND suplier ='" . $suplier . " '";
```

A third way to accomplish the same goal is to use the concatenation assignment operator. (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

```
$sql  = "select stoks,srate,prate,taxp,";
$sql .= "iname,suplier,icod from stock where iname='".$item_name."'";
$sql .= " AND  suplier ='".$suplier." '";
```

There are other ways to accomplish the same idea, but these seem to be the most popular.

Comment: So PHP behaves in that regard like C, Perl, etc. right?

Answer (score 3):

PHP doesn't require it, but you can also concatenate strings in a similar fashion:

```
$myString = "Hello my name is john I am a super cool dude that likes cheese" .
"I also like milk" .
"I also like the number 8";
```

Answer (score 2):

Current answers explain how to continue a concatenation. But what about any other expression, like `a + b + c + ... ;`?

You can use parenthesis to achieve expression continuation (which includes the concatenation). So, you can write expressions like:

```
# A chain of conditions
$apply = (
       $condition1
    && $condition2
    && $conditionn);

# your example sql expression
$sql = (
      "select stoks,srate,prate,taxp,"
    . "iname,suplier,icod from stock where iname='"
    . item_name.Text
    . "'"
    . "and  suplier ='"
    . suplier.Text
    . " '");
```